# Trying to create an instance of a struct with an predefined image. Unsure if struct or instance code is off

Tags: ios, swift, struct, instance

So I have created the following struct :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct restaurantmodel {
    var restitle: String
    var restype: String
    var resimage: UIImage(named: "")
}
```

and an instance of this struct

```
let restaurant1 = restaurantmodel(
    restitle: "earth cafe",
    restype: "Chicken",
    resimage: UIImage(named: "earth.png")
)
```

I have tried a number of different wordings in the struct and instance (image vs image view vs image view (named: ""), and I am not having luck with any of my variations.

Can someone tell me how to reference an image view in a struct and then how to specify a picture in an instance from that same struct?

Comment: learning more and more about question requirements.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the struct like this

```
struct RestaurantModel{
    var restitle: String
    var restype: String
    var resimage: UIImage?
}
```

And create an instance like this

```
let restaurant = RestaurantModel(restitle: "Test",
    restype: "Test",resimage: UIImage(named: "1.png"))
```

Comment: and what is the purpose of the question mark in the struct?  what does that suggest?

Comment: it is for swift optionals. this means the the resImage can also take a nil value. if you are sure resimage will always have a value, you can skip the `?` character. read more about optionals here http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/